# Using Scrapy with certificate authenticated and logged in user session?

Tags: python, certificate, scrapy, scrape

In the Scrapy docs, there is the following example for how to use an authenticated session in Scrapy with with log in data:

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'example.com'
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return

    # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

But is there a way to do this authentication using certificate log in?

Comment: Could you provide more information about that login method? Are we talking about X.509?

Comment: Was this issue solved? I am having the same problem and it would be great to know if anyone was able to fix it.

Comment: Try using other method to generate the requests. 

API v1:

 

$ curl --cert ./cert.pem:my_passphrase -u "user:pass" "https://certs.qualysguard.qualys.com/msp/about.php"  
 

 

API v2:

$ curl --cert ./cert.pem:my_passphrase -u "user:pass" -H "X-Requested-With:curl"  "https://certs.qualysguard.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/scan/?action=list"